# How can an NFL team with a worse win-loss record than a division rival clinch a playoff berth before their rival?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

As of week 16 of the 2015 NFL season, the top two AFC West teams are the Broncos and the Chiefs. Specifically:

[image: Broncos 10-4, Chiefs 10-5]

Notice the x next to the Chiefs indicates they have clinched the playoffs. So they could go 10-6 and still make the playoffs. But with two games left, the Broncos obviously could at worst wind up going 10-6. So both can go 10-6. **Why is KC in but not Denver?**

Additional Info:

Currently no other wild card team seems to have a chance of attaining a better record than 10-6. As you can see from this table,

[image: Jets 10-5, Steelers 9-6, Bills & Colts 7-8]

the Jets and the Steelers are the only two teams who have a chance to go 10-6. Also note, both of these teams have larger net total points than the Broncos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: the good divisional record (at worst 4-2) and excellent conference record for the Chiefs (at worst 9-3) means that they win the tiebreakers over the other relevant teams (Broncos, Jets and Steelers).

**How the Broncos can miss the playoffs**

The Broncos lose to both the Bengals and the Chargers, while the Chiefs beat the Raiders. The Chiefs win the AFC West with an 11-5 record, while the Broncos are in the wild card mix with a 10-6 record.

At this point, the other important teams are the Jets and the Steelers. The "worst case" scenario for the Broncos is both the Jets and the Steelers winning; in this case, the Jets have an 11-5 record and claim the first wild card spot. The Steelers have the same 10-6 record as the Broncos, but claim the second wild card spot on the basis of their better conference record (7-5 vs 6-6).

**Why the Chiefs always make the playoffs**

If the Chiefs win their final match, they are 11-5. At this point, they are either AFC West champions or guaranteed to have one of the two best records of non-champions (the only other non-champion which can possibly get to 11-5 is the Jets), so they are guaranteed a playoff spot.

If the Chiefs lose their final match against the Raiders, they have a 10-6 record. If the Broncos have lost their final two matches, the Chiefs are AFC West champions on the basis of their better divisional record (4-2 vs 3-3) as the Broncos and Chiefs split their two matches this year.

If the Broncos win one of their final two matches, they are 11-5 and AFC West champions, while the Chiefs are in the wild card mix. The important teams are once again the Jets and the Steelers - if they both win, the Jets again claim the first wild card spot at 11-5, and the Steelers are at 10-6. The Chiefs win the tiebreaker on the basis of their better conference record (9-3 vs 7-5). A similar analysis applies if the Jets lose.

Comment: So, if two teams are tied in their division, then conference record as opposed to head to head wins/loses vs each other takes precedence in determining who wins?  Btw ur profile picture is super cool. Love the photography technique.

Comment: @StanShunpike I'd view this [list of tiebreakers](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1702) to answer your question.